# how to synchronisation over multiple mobile devices

Tags: ios, grails, synchronization, frontend, backend

Is there anyone who worked out a synchronisation plan for a mobile application? I've been searching for it, but can't find a good example. I'm looking for a plan such as I think evernote uses to sync the files on the mobile phone with the backend.

My current plan:
- when you start the app: all your files will be downloaded from the backend using you username and password
- when you create a new object and there is network connection: object is stored localy in the core data (IOS), and transferred to the backend
- when you create a new object, but there is no network connection: the object is stored locally, and transferred when you are connected to the network and press sync.

All suggestions are welcome!

tahnks!

Sorry, I did forget some important information...

- I'm using a grails backend
- the frontend (mobile application) is an IOS app

Is there a good way to make sure there are nog file/version conflicts between the different devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cold use various ways. 
At my advice, the best one is to use the Parse framework. It is very easy to use and simple. Log in and save objet all in one. Please visit this: http://parse.com

Otherwise, You can use iCloud to store and synchronize your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Find the Mobile Backend-as-a-Service (MBaaS) that fits your app best.

[This link](http://www.optimusmobility.com/2013/04/05/top-5-backend-as-a-service-providers-for-mobile/) can get you started in your search.